# How to pass params to token referenced by variable?

Tags: raku

I can easily use token signatures by using token name directly:

```
my token t ( $x ) { $x };

'axb' ~~ / 'a' <t: 'x'> 'b' /;      # match
'axb' ~~ / 'a' <t( 'x' )> 'b' /;    # match
```

However I haven't found a way to do this, when token is stored in variable:

```
my $t = token ( $x ) { $x };

'axb' ~~ / 'a' <$t: 'x'> 'b' /;
'axb' ~~ / 'a' <$t( 'x' )> 'b' /;
```

Both give:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ...
Unable to parse expression in metachar:sym<assert>; couldn't find final '>'
```

What is the magic syntax to do that?

BTW: I've even browsed Raku test suite and it does not include such case in `roast/S05-grammar/signatures.t`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either:

- Use the solution in jnthn's answer to let Raku explicitly know you wish to use your `$` sigil'd token variable as a [`Callable`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Callable).
- Declare the variable as explicitly being `Callable` in the first place and make the corresponding change in the call:

```
my &t = token ( $x ) { $x };

say 'axb' ~~ / 'a' <&t: 'x'> 'b' /;   # ｢axb｣
say 'axb' ~~ / 'a' <&t( 'x' )> 'b' /; # ｢axb｣
```

Comment: Might be of use to point out that tokens are just regexen with certain attributes set, and regexen are, in turn, Callables, hence they can go into `&` variables.

Comment: Thanks! While jnthn answered my question very directly I'm flagging this one as an answer, because it emphasizes the real cause of my problem - wrong sigil. Treating token as Callable from the start is much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 11):

Place an `&` before the variable:

```
my $t = token ( $x ) { $x };
say 'axb' ~~ / 'a' <&$t: 'x'> 'b' /;
say 'axb' ~~ / 'a' <&$t( 'x' )> 'b' /;
```

The parser looks for the `&`, and then delegates to the Raku variable parse rule, which will happily parse a contextualizer like this.